# Buy this get that product

Tags: magento-1.9, promotions

I'm working in magento 1.9 version.

I have done the following features using Promotion codes:

> Buy 1 Get 1

but, I want to implement the following concepts

> Buy this(let say Prod A) Get that (let say Prod B)
>
> Buy x num of prod and get Y num of products

How to do this. Is there any free or paid extensions available for this.

I found [this](http://blog.gaiterjones.com/free-magento-extension-buy-one-get-one-free-discounted/) free extension. But it is not working.

Comment: my idea to create a bundle product and set price of one product

Comment: Okay. Thanks @MurtuzaZabuawala. Is any free extions available for this.

Comment: blog.goods-pro.com/wp-uploads/2010/07/BuyXGetY.tar.gz please check this I dont know it works or not

Comment: i have checked it. Seems it is not working, ;)

Comment: create a bundle product idea is best you can try that one

Answer (score 1):

The functionality you require is not available out the box.

Some of my ramblings:

As an ecommerce platform, it has always been surprising to me that there was no extensive gifting ability included as standard. Even as an enterprise edition feature.

The proposed bundle product idea will potentially work for you. I have not tried it. never even considered it before.

In my view, one major aspect of gifting, is the perception to the end-user, that they had gotten something for free. Refering back to the proposed solution, the user would not get as an effective notion that they had just been gifted some items.

Nothing speeks clearer to this than some additional line items in the cart, set at the gifted price. Gifting does not necasarily mean free.

To this end, there exists a multitude of extensions available. Some free, some not. Paid for do not necasarily mean better than free. You usually get better and more prompt support, if needed.

Having magento perform gifting is actually difficult. Any extention that offers extensive gifting capabilities would need to change some core functionalities, to some extend.

Due to this, you may find an extension that works great for others, may not work for you. It all depends on what other 3rd party extensions you got installed, which also change behaviour.

Sometimes they just work, other times they need a bit of tweaking by the developers to get it working just right in your setup. This is where paid support usually wins.

Depending on your time factor, it could just be best to try another extension, if the one you got does not work out the box. Gifting capabilities can be approached in different ways. Another extension could just work.

Ok, so end my ramblings.

Pertaining your question, I will of course put forth my own extension:

http://www.proxiblue.com.au/premium-modules/magento-free-gift-promotions-extension.html

I created this a few years back after no other gifting solution suited my needs.

A google search will easily reveal others.

Good luck with your promption.

Answer (score 0):

for your problem you dont need any extension, just create bundle product and set price of one product .

and that will work.

Hope this will Help you.